# Android Device is not register into parse installation

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Right now I am using following code:

```
Parse.initialize(this, Constant.PARSE_APPLICATIONID,
Constant.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation
                        .getCurrentInstallation();

                installation.put(Constant.TAG_USER_OBJECTID, user.getObjectId());
                installation.put(Constant.TAG_IS_ENABLED, true);
                installation.saveInBackground();
```

And also try with following code too.

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("com.parse.push",
            "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
        } else {
            Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
        }    
    }
});
```

So, that using above code my android device is not register into ParseInstallation class.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this solve it for me, trust me you are going to laugh when you read it, parse tells you to add this to your gradle

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
```

When in reality you have to add this (at the time I did it those were the current versions try the same thing with yours if you are in a not long distance future)

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.3.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
```

That solve my problem I hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but i am implementing on Eclipse, So it will not be used.Thanks again for comments.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct versions of the jars files maybe is that. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Create a class Application extends from android.app.Application and override onCreate method initialize your parse in this onCreate like this...

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, MainActivity.APP_ID, MainActivity.CLIENT_KEY);

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Moosa Baloch for comment, but i already use this code but still not working..